# Result by server Date

Tags: mysql

how to add query result as current date and less days. do not want fixed days pl help in mysql

```
select
Winner,
Coupon,
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Date`
FROM table2
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y')
LIMIT 1, 30
```

[image: displayed list]

Comment: So you want only results that have passed?

Comment: yes i received all dates result i do not want grater than system date !

Comment: thanks working fine!

Comment: How to show just 1 row by current date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `where` clause to that statement and use `<= now()` to get the rows less than or equal to the current datetime.

```
select
Winner,
Coupon,
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Date`
FROM table2
where datecolumn<=now()
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

You can use `limit 1` to return just one row. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Your current limit statement, `LIMIT 1, 30`, is returning the second row though the thirty first row (the first value is the offset, the second is the number of rows).